# A question from test (recursive designing) - Trees - Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

I tried to answer the following 2 question, they are from a Java course test, but it is a little confusing because of the recursive that I'm probably need to use.

The first one is a method that receive a root of a binary tree and returns the maximum value on tree. (example in figure A).

**This question** (and the second) says only complete in the missing lines:

```
public static int maxInTree (Node root)
{
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    if ((root.getLeftSon() == null) && (root.getRightSon() == null))
        ______________________    // I think that here: *return 1*;
    if (root.getLeftSon() == null)
    return _________________
    if (___________ == null)    // I think that here: *root.getRightSon()*
    _______________________________-
    return max______________________________
}
```

The second question says: do the same as the first question BUT for a **sorted binary search tree**.

```
public static int maxInSearchTree (Node r)
{
    if (r == null)
        return 0;
    if (r.getRightSon() == null)
        __________________________
    return _______________________________
}
```

You can assume there is a method to pullout the father: *getNumber()*.

thnx !!

Comment: I can tell you straight away that '// I think that here: *return 1*;
' is wrong, unless the root node happens to contain the value `1`. If the root has no child nodes (where did this 'son' term come from - is that an American thing?), then the tree only contains one node (value) and therefore the maximum value has to be the value of the root node itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that getNumber() gives the value (not the father).

```
public static int maxInTree (Node root)
{
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    if ((root.getLeftSon() == null) && (root.getRightSon() == null))
        return root.getNumber();
    if (root.getLeftSon() == null)
        return max(root.getNumber(), maxInTree(root.getRightSon()));
    if (root.getRightSon() == null)
        return max(root.getNumber(), maxInTree(root.getLeftSon()));
    return max(root.getNumber(),
        max(maxInTree(root.getLeftSon()),maxInTree(root.getRightSon())));
}

public static int maxInSearchTree (Node r)
{
    if (r == null)
        return 0;
    if (r.getRightSon() == null)
        return r.getNumber();
    return maxInSearchTree(r.getRightSon());
}
```

Comment: Something missing in: 'return max(root.getNumber(),'.
thnx

Comment: @Master no, there's nothing missing, the expression is just continued on the next line. @Maurice I'd say that the recursion in `maxInSearchTree` should be the same method rather than `maxInTree`, since you know the subtree is sorted as well :)

Comment: @Thomas Good point, though I'd go one step further and point out that it's not even recursion if it doesn't call itself.

Comment: @Thomas, about the max function, can I use it without mention the Math Class ? like: Math.max... etc... ?

Comment: @Master: yes, with a static import: import static java.lang.Math.max;

Answer (score 1):

You should think about the layout of the tree as well as the result that is desired.
Some hints:

- if there is no root, return whatever is appropriate
- if there is no child, return the current node's (root of a subtree) value
- if there is a child, recurse into it
- if the tree is sorted, the right child's value should always be greater than the node's and the left child's
- if the tree is not sorted, you need to compare each node's value and remember the highest one (`max(...)`)

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, since Thomas covered a lot of what I would have said already. However, a few additional hints:

The left and right child nodes of your root node are themselves the root nodes of the left and right sub-trees. With that considered, to get the maximum value of your left and right sub-trees, you need to call your recursive `maxInTree(Node node)` method with the left or right child as your argument.

If your unordered tree only has a left OR right sub-tree, then the maximum value is the greater of the root nodes value and the maximum value in the left or right sub-tree.